# Choosing lens for a studio to record classes

Tags: lens, field-of-view, calculations, studio-setup

I'm building a home studio to record Math classes: I have a blackboard (1,90m width by 1,20m height) and the distance from the camera to the blackboard would be around 1,80m (on a tripod, 1,70m from the ground).

How can I calculate the lens I should buy to record the full width and height of the blackboard?

I'm planning on buying a Canon 70D for the studio.

Thank you.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit at video.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is your only concern covering the field of view of the blackboard? We have existing questions which cover how to calculate that.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57943/how-to-calculate-the-correct-focal-length-needed-for-a-subject-of-a-given-size-a

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/what-is-the-formula-for-percent-of-frame-filled-at-a-specific-distance-and-focal?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record with 3:2 still pictures, or 16:9 movies?  It matters, a little.  Assuming the later, see a field of view calculator at http://www.scantips.com/lights/fieldofview.html

Canon 70D is a 3:2 1.6x 22.5x15mm DSLR, but offers 16:9 movies, which is a complication (HD format is only 12.65 tall usable).

Instructions:

Enter 1.8 m distance at top,

Enter 1.6x crop and 16:9 in a 3:2 DSLR in option 3,

Select option 5, and specify there to use option 3 sensor and to find focal length for 1.2m Vertical,

then it computes field of view H 2.13 and V 1.20 meters

with a 19mm lens

Or recording 3:2 still pictures computes 22.5mm focal lens is 1.8 x 1.2 m field of view.

Comment: 20mm should work too